# Can I avoid buying a ridiculously expensive replacement starter motor?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, triumph, starter

My situation can be described with a photo:
[image]

That's my starter motor, which doesn't appear to be in a healthy condition.

What I would like to know is, can I avoid spending over $500 on a new one in any reasonable way? Getting a used one on ebay or any other online shopping place is not an option, as I need it fixed in one week max and getting an used item is slow and risky. Delivery is slow to Romania and I get the risk of getting a defective one, or one that will break down soon.

Can it be rebuilt with commonly available components?

Can I adapt another starter from a different motorcycle model? This particular model is known to break down easily, so it would be great to adapt a more reliable model if it's possible.

Technical details:

- Motorcycle: Triumph Tiger 800 from 2011
- Starter: Denso 428000-5540

Thanks!

Comment: As the other posters have said, I'm pretty confident you can find a local shop that refurbs starters, alternators, etc and have them fit new new brushes and clean it up.  Much, much cheaper.  Good luck, would like to know the outcome.

Comment: My experience with rebuilders (if you can find a good one) is that many times they can  correct  defects in the original design by using different but compatible (read better) parts than OEM.

Comment: It looks like push start is an option
http://www.triumphrat.net/air-cooled-twins-technical-talk/204022-push-start-efi-bike.html

Comment: End result: I replaced with Denso brushes ordered online, and the rotor was polished a bit to remove a groove that was formed in it. Costing me about 15% or the price of the whole part. Still, because of that rotor polishing, if the starter breaks down again and the rotor is affected again, it may become unsalvageable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the picture it looks as if your brushes are completely worn out. If there's no other fault, that is (theoretically) an easy and cheap fix. It appears however that getting brushes for this particular starter isn't as easy as it normally should be.

For more information have a look at this thread:
http://www.tiger800.co.uk/index.php/topic,11947.0.html

as well as this (in German), which is referenced in the previous one:
[http://www.tigerhome.de/index.php?/topic/28918-anlasserbürsten/](http://www.tigerhome.de/index.php?/topic/28918-anlasserb%C3%BCrsten/)

Ask a local automotive electrician/mechanic, with a bit of luck they'll be able to sort you out quickly and for a reasonable price.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I ordered those parts listed in the German language forum, still I was looking to secure a backup plan in case they don't arrive on time. Do you know if you can adapt other brushes?

Answer (score 4):

There are companies that can recondition these, at least here in the UK. I have had one of mine done before in a couple of days. I assume they must use common components due to the fast turn around.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know they usually can be reconditioned, but can mine also be fixed in the state it appears to be?

Comment: I reckon so, the brushes are normally worn or the switch faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys on this web side I bought my spare parts for my denso starter motor for a Tiger 2012. After around 40.000km the started motor was getting very slow and the brusher were on the very end of there life time-->starting was a gamble

Number on my starter motor is denso 428000-5540

https://www.al-electric.de/index.php?aktion=nummernsuche&nummer=428000-5540%22

article no for  sigle brushes 028530-5312 or the other part with the plastic housing attached 028530-5302, Isolator is the 028512-5470

All in all I repaired my starter for around 40€.